# Can't get entry for specific email as primary calendar

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

I'm using `Google Calendar API` with a service account. Actually I'm going to create an application that synchronize the events from a local database to a specific email user. The adding of an event seems working pretty well but the problem's coming when I need to update an event. In particular before the update I check if the event exist or not on the `Google Calendar` of a specific user, let me show an example, this is how I create the service account:

```
string[] scopes = new string[]
{
     CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, 
     CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly
};

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(CPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                 new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("my service account email")
            {
                  Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

CalendarService service = new CalendarService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName
            });

 return service;
```

before updating or adding an event I check if the event exist in this way:

```
public bool EventExist(string id)
{
     try
     {
         var service = AuthenticationService();
         Event foundResponse = service.Events.Get("foo@gmail.com", id).Execute(); //id is the id of the event
            return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.Write(ex.Message);
         return false;
     }
}
```

Now `AuthenticationService()` service is the method that return the `service` variable (the first code wrote). Later, I use the `service` variable for get the event of a specific user, note that the `email` is the primary calendar of the user. Now if I pass "primary", the event was found, instead if I pass the email, as in this case, the event was not found.

I don't know why, maybe the `service-account` save the event of a specific user somewhere? This situation is very bad for me, 'cause if an user delete an event with a particular id I need to check if the element exist or not into the calendar of the user.

Maybe I'm wrong with something or Google don't allow to do this?

Comment: If you are using the "primary" keyword then the event is saved on the calendar of the service account instead on the calendar of the user. You should use Oauth2 and authenticate the specific user instead of the service account and then the primary keyword would put it to the user's calendar.